# SelectDateWidget - how get to each subfield separately?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In project there is used `SelectDateWidget` and to render it in template it only need to write `form.date_of_sth`, but it renders all widgets (selects) in one. I would like to render each one separately. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.11:

Import the widget that you want to modify. Your choices can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets

Create a subclass and specify the template name.

```
# app/widgets.py
from django.forms.widgets import DefaultWidget

class CustomWidget(DefaultWidget):
    template_name = 'app/widget.html'
```

Create your template. This is copied exactly from django/forms/widgets/multiwidget.html but you can put anything you want here. You can also reference other existing widget templates for inspiration. Your choice can be found here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets

```
# app/templates/app/widget.html
{% spaceless %}
    {% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
        {% include widget.template_name %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Import your CustomWidget and add it to a field in your form.

```
# app/forms.py
from django import forms
from .widgets import CustomWidget

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.ExampleField(widget=CustomWidget())
```

Finally, in your template, render the main field and it will reference app/templates/app/widget.html to render each subfield manually based on the template you created.